# What should I return to the view to confirm that a a process has been successful?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Suppose I have a registration page. It's a simple view with just "Name" and "Email" input boxes. When the user submits their details, the controller will create the user in the database and then return the (same) view.

Now that the same view is being returned, I want the view to detect that the process was successful. I.e. I need to pass something back to the view to let it display something slightly different. The page is essentially the same, but instead of input boxes I have some text "Successfully registered".

One way to do this:

```
ViewBag.RegistrationWasSuccessful = True
```

Then in the view simply check to see if that variable is true, then display the "success" text.

Another way is to add it to the model:

```
Function Registration(ByVal model as RegistrationView) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        model.RegistrationWasSuccessful = True
    End If
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

Again, check to see if that variable is true.

What's the best way to check if a form was successful? The methods above seem a little ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for the cleanest, easiest way to display a success or fail message depending on process success/failure, I suggest instead, adding a message to your ViewBag and Post a success or fail message in your View.

In your Controller

```
if processSuccess == true
   ViewBag.RegistrationMessage = "Success"
else 
   ViewBag.RegistrationMessage = "Failure"
```

In your View display

```
<span> @ViewBag.RegistrationMessage </span>
```

Comment: What about not displaying the input boxes? I'll need an If statement in there right? Maybe just {If ViewBag.Registration = "Success"}?

Comment: @RowanFreeman, I must have missed that part. I focused on avoiding messiness. You won't get around the condition statements for that... You could put them into your Viewbag or a Partial. But I wouldn't recommend going that far. Some messiness will come with flexibility. As much as I crave clean Views, they will get a little messy.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Yeah I was trying to avoid that messyness. I hate having conditional statements in views and displaying things slightly differently. I guess I'll just stick with ViewBag.